# page life cycle when OnServerValidate fails (custom validator)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview within an update panel. When the page loads I have javascript enable/disable fields in the gridview (call it Function X(). When the update panel updates I use `Sys.Application.add_load()` to reload Function X(). This is all fine and dandy.

**My problem**:
When the custom validator's onservervalidate fails (`args.IsValid = false`) Function X() is not called and it needs to be called to enable/disable fields. How do I call Function X() at this point in the life cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to manually re-call your JavaScript functions, and you can do so like this, using JavaScript:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
  functionX();
}
```